# Foreach loop to Lambda or simpler LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, linq, foreach, lambda, attributes

Can the following code be converted to lambda expression or simpler LINQ query

```
string str = "";
foreach (string key in (FindControl("Q" + QNo + "AnswerTA") as HtmlTextArea).Attributes.Keys)
              {
                str += key +","+ (FindControl("Q" + QNo + "AnswerTA") as HtmlTextArea).Attributes[key] + "|";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly simplify it to this:

```
var control = FindControl("Q" + QNo + "AnswerTA") as HtmlTextArea;

string str = "";
foreach (string key in control.Attributes.Keys)
{
  str += key +","+ control.Attributes[key] + "|";
}
```

But any LinQ statement would take even more code and look more confusing to me.

```
string str = control.Attributes.Keys.Select(key => key +","+ control.Attributes[key] + "|")
                                    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, n) => c + n);
```

If only [AttributeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) implemented `IEnumerable<>` for it's pairs. But it seems it does not.

Comment: the second statement is giving a compile time error "icollection does not contain a definition for select"

Comment: hm, maybe you are missing the `using` statement for `System.Linq`, but maybe those classes are so old that they don't implement the correct interfaces.

Comment: I am using System.Linq